# Xamarin forms UWP app doesn't resize elements after window resize

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I have a simple XF UWP app with a couple pages. I've found that if I resize the window, the active page resizes its elements fine, but the inactive page doesn't. The inactive page retains the same layout as before the window resize.

Steps to reproduce:

- Navigate from page 1 to page 2.
- Resize the window.
- Go back to page 1. It retains the prior layout.
- Resize the window again, then page 1 finally adjust its elements size and layout.

[image: Xamarin Forms UWP resize]

I have tried execuing ForceLayout() and UpdateChildrenLayout(), but the problem remains.
What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Do you have xaml code to share with us ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT No code to share, but you can replicate the issue just by creating a  Xamarin Forms UWP project with a flyout template in VS 2019. I created a bug report with a detailed description on how to reproduce this at https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14498

Comment: OK, I will check this bug report link.